# How to use list of sparse tensors in tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix, tf.keras, tf.data.dataset

I'm trying to build a model which takes list of sparse tensors as input. (list length is equal to batch size)

The reason I use sparse tensor is that I have to pass adjacency matrix to my GNN model and it is very sparse. (~99%)

I'm familiar with using pytorch, and it is very easy to feed sparse tensor into the network.

However I found that I have to use tf.data.Dataset or keras.utils.Sequence for making dataset in tensorflow.

But those methods throw error to me when I use list of sparse tensors as input.

For example, code below makes TypeError

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(sparse_lists)
```

```py
TypeError: Neither a SparseTensor nor SparseTensorValue: 
[<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7fbf2e25b5c0>, 
<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7fbf2c22ada0>, 
<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7fbf2c22a400>, 
<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7fbf2c1ed240>, 
<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7fbf2c1ed390>, 
<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7fbf2c1ed470>, 
<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7fbf2c1ed5c0>, 
<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7fbf2c1ed710>, 
<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7fbf2c1ed828>, 
<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7fbf2c1ed940>].
```

I know that it will work if I concat all sparse tensors in list as a huge tensor.
However it is not my option because I have to use indexing for sparse tensors later.
(If I concat 2D sparse tensors into 3D sparse tensors, I cannot use indexing like below)

```py
Some3DSparseTensor[:10]
```

Also, it will take more time because I have to slice 3D tensors for matrix multiplication with other dense networks.

Furthermore, I know that it will be fine if I make sparse tensor by indices, values for every batch, but it would take too much time for each batch.

As a result, I want to make tf.data.Dataset to be able to generate batch from list of sparse tensors due to indexing, time issue.

Can anybody help me? :)

---

Long story short,

What I have: List of sparse tensors (e.g 1000000 length list)

What I need to do: Batch list of sparse tensors (e.g 1024 length list, not a sparse concat)

Comment: Does all the SparseTensors have the same `dense_shape`?

Comment: Yes @LGrementieri

Comment: So a single element of your dataset is a list of 1024 sparse tensors, right? How is your batch made? Is it a list of batched sparse tensors? Could you please provide an example of the shapes of a single element that you would like to have in the dataset?

Comment: @LGrementieri If I have a list of sparse tensors like `[sp1, sp2, ... sp100000]`, I want batches to be like `[sp1, sp2, ... sp1024], [sp1025, ... sp2048]` and so on. I just thought that `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(sparse_lists).batch(1024)` would make it, but not as well. Each sparse tensor (sp) has `(2000, 2000)` dense shape.

Comment: Now it is much clearer, but I still don't get why the `.batch` solution followed by the conversion to list inside the training loop cannot be a solution. The memory consumption of a single batched sparse tensor and of a list of sparse tensors is the same.

Comment: @LGrementieri Sorry for inconvenience. It is because I have to iterate list of tensors inside the [call()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#call) function of TF2. TF doesn't allow iteration of sparse tensors so I have to slice it in `call()` function and iterate it. Also, it doesn't support batch multiplication for sparse tensor. So I believe this extra slice step makes training slow.

Answer (score 0):

If the SparseTensors have the same `dense_shape` you can create a unique SparseTensor instead of a list and pass it to `from_tensor_slices`.

For example the following code produce separate SparseTensors from a large SparseTensor `s` splitting them along the first dimension

```
s = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(
    indices=tf.constant([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 1]], dtype=tf.int64), 
    values=tf.range(4, dtype=tf.float32), 
    dense_shape=(3, 2, 2))
d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(s)
for t in d:
    print(t)
>>> SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor([[0 0]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([0.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([2 2], shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
[[0 0]
 [0 1]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([1. 2.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([2 2], shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor([[1 1]], shape=(1, 2), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([3.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([2 2], shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
```

To use `from_tensor_slices` in this way, you need a function to convert the list `sparse_lists` to a large SparseTensor `s` (reported below).

To recap, you can do

```
import tensorflow as tf

def sparse_list_to_sparse_tensor(sparse_lists):
    n = len(sparse_lists)
    shape = sparse_lists[0].dense_shape
    out_shape = (n, *shape)
    out_values = tf.concat([s.values for s in sparse_lists], axis=0)
    out_indices = []
    for i, s in enumerate(sparse_lists):
        element_idx = tf.cast(tf.fill((s.indices.shape[0], 1), i), dtype=tf.int64)
        out_indices.append(tf.concat([element_idx, s.indices], axis=1))
    out_indices = tf.concat(out_indices, axis=0)
    return tf.sparse.SparseTensor(out_indices, out_values, out_shape)


tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(sparse_list_to_sparse_tensor(sparse_lists))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but as I mentioned "I know that it will work if I concat all sparse tensors in list as a huge tensor". I have over 100 million sparse tensors so it takes too much time to concat all those sparse tensors for every training. ( saving the huge sparse tensor can be a method but, I need to use 'indexing' for train-test split randomly )

Comment: By the way, thanks for efficient method to concat all sparse tensors.
I just used tf.sparse.expand_dims() and tf.sparse.concat() to concatenation.
I found that your method is much faster (~5x)

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant with "concat all sparse tensors" because I haven't understood the problem posed by this solution. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Please check out my latest solution that does not use concatenation of sparse tensors.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution uses `from_tensor_slices` on every sparse tensor (after the addition of a dummy batch dimension) to create many datasets with a single element that can be concatenated in a single dataset.

```
dataset = None
for sparse_tensor in sparse_list:
    batched_sparse_tensor = tf.sparse.expand_dims(sparse_tensor, axis=0)
    element_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(batched_sparse_tensor)
    if dataset is None:
        dataset = element_dataset
    else:
        dataset = dataset.concatenate(element_dataset)
```

Notice that using this solution the sparse tensors can have different `dense_shape`s.

Comment: Sorry I think I posted my question badly. What I really want to do now is to pass "list of sparse tensors" into call() function because I need to iterate list of sparse tensors in it. However, it generates another sparse tensor.(which I have to slice it to iterate in call() function). Anyway, thanks for letting me know the `concatenate` function in tf.data.Dataset. / I edited my question in the last section